# Problema al sumar los valores de un array

Tags: nodejs, angular, firebase

Hola a todos estoy comenzando a programar y me surgió un problema al realizar la suma de un arreglo para poder mostrar un total en pantalla. Al agregar un ítem de mi carrito me sale lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar refresh en el navegador se "soluciona",
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
no es el comportamiento deseado pero no logro encontrar donde se produce ese error.
Aqui dejo mi codigo

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CarritoService } from '../../services/carrito.service';
import { Pedidos } from '../../models/pedidos.models';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-carrito',
  templateUrl: './carrito.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carrito.component.css']
})
export class CarritoComponent implements OnInit {

  public subTotal = 0;
  public arregItems: Pedidos[] = [];
  public subTotales = [] as any;
  constructor(private carritoservice: CarritoService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.carritoservice.obtenerPedido().subscribe((pedido: Pedidos[]) => {
      this.arregItems = pedido;
    });
    this.carritoservice.obtenerItemDelPedido().subscribe(
      pedidos =>{
         pedidos.find((pedidos) => {
          const sbt = pedidos.subTotalserv;
          this.subTotales.push(sbt);
          console.log(this.subTotales);
          const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
          this.subTotal = this.subTotales.reduce(reducer);
          console.log(this.subTotal);
        });
      }
    );
  }
  borrarItem(){
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Borrar item del carrito',
      text: '¿Quieres quitar este item del carrito?',
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Si, quitar item',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        Swal.fire(
          'Item borrado',
          'Su articulo ha sido quitado del carrito'
        );
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar desde ya lo agradezco.
Saludos!!!

Comment: Empieza por arreglar los nombres de funciones y variables: `pedidos.find((pedidos) => { ...` Tienes una función anónima que recibe como parámetro una variable que se llama igual que el objeto sobre el que aplicas `find`. Si es un error de tipeo, corrígelo. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, gracias por tu sugerencia. Lo cambie pero sigue con el mismo problema. Pienso que a lo mejor ese error se da por la suscripción al observable, pero como no tengo mucha experiencia no logro corregirlo.